# Kaczmarz animation

Tags: algorithm, matlab, animation, plot

i am asking for help.. I want to animate the Kaczmarz method on Matlab. It's method allows to find solution of system of equations by the serial projecting solution vector on hyperplanes, which which is given by the eqations of system. 
And i want make animation of this vector moving (like the point is going on the projected vectors).

```
%% System of equations
% 2x + 3y = 4;
% x - y = 2;
% 6x + y = 15;
%%

A = [2 3;1 -1; 6 1];
f = [4; 2; 15];
resh = pinv(A)*f
x = -10:0.1:10;
e1 = (1 - 2*x)/3;
e2 = (x - 2);
e3 = 15 - 6*x;

plot(x,e1)
grid on
%
axis([0 4 -2 2])
hold on
plot(x,e2)
hold on
plot(x,e3)
hold on

precision = 0.001; % точность
iteration = 100; % количество итераций
lambda = 0.75; % лямбда

[m,n] = size(A);
x = zeros(n,1);
%count of norms
for i = 1:m
   nrm(i) = norm(A(i,:));
end

for i = 1:1:iteration
   j = mod(i-1,m) + 1;
   if (nrm(j) <= 0), continue, end;
   predx = x; 
   x = x + ((f(j) - A(j,:)*x)*A(j,:)')/(nrm(j))^2; 
   p = plot(x);
   set(p)
   %pause 0.04;
   hold on;
   if(norm(predx - x) <= precision), break, end
end
```

I wrote the code for this method, by don't imagine how make the animation, how I can use the `set` function.

Comment: As an extra random comment: In tomography, the place where the Kaczman method is most used, they call it ART (algebraic reconstruction technique)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code there are a lot of redundant and random pieces. Do not call `hold on` more than once, it does nothing. Also `set(p)` does nothing, you want to set some `p`s properties to something, then you use `set`.

Also, you are plotting the result, but not the "change". The change is a line between the previous and current, and that is the only reason you'd want to have a variable such as `predx`, to plot. SO USE IT!

Anyway, this following code plots your algorithm. I added a repeated line to plot in green and then delete, so you can see what the last step does. I also changed the plots in the begging to just plot in red  so its more clear what is each of the things.

Change your loop for:

```
for i = 1:1:iteration
    j = mod(i-1,m) + 1;
    if (nrm(j) <= 0), continue, end;
    predx = x;
    x = x + ((f(j) - A(j,:)*x)*A(j,:)')/(nrm(j))^2;




    plot([predx(1) x(1)],[predx(2) x(2)],'b'); %plot line
    c=plot([predx(1) x(1)],[predx(2) x(2)],'g'); %plot it in green
    pause(0.1)
    children = get(gca, 'children'); %delete the green line
    delete(children(1));

    drawnow
%     hold on;
    if(norm(predx - x) <= precision), break, end
end
```

This will show:

[image]