# Python plotting lines in a loop

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib

I need to plot every iteration in a loop of Kachmarz algorithm. But when i try there is a error:

```
ValueError: x and y can be no greater than 2-D, but have shapes (2, 1, 1) and (2,)
```

Threre is my code (we have matrix A, where every row give a plane and it has to solve Ax = f by Kaczmarz algorithm and animate it):

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg as la

x = np.linspace(-100, 15, 100)
A = np.matrix([[2, 3], [1, -1],[6,  1]]);
f = np.matrix([4, 2, 15]);
resh = la.pinv(A).dot(np.transpose(f))

e1 = (1 - 2*x)/3;
e2 = (x - 2);
e3 = 15 - 6*x;

plt.plot(x, e1, color="black")
plt.plot(x, e2, color="black")
plt.plot(x, e3, color="black")
plt.axis([-0, 4, -4, 4])

[m , n] = np.shape(A)

precision = 0.01
iteration = 100
lmbd = 0.8

nrm=[]
for i in range(0, m):
   nrm.append(la.norm(A[i][:]));

approx = np.zeros((n, 1))
predx  =

 np.zeros((n, 1))
print(np.shape(approx))
for i in range(0, iteration):
    j = (i-1) % m
    predx = approx
        approx = approx + np.multiply((f[:,j] - A[j,:].dot(approx)),(np.transpose(A[j, :])))
    plt.plot([predx[0], approx[0]], [predx[1], 2], "r-")
    # c = plt.plot([predx[1], 2], [predx[2], 2], "g-")
    # pause(0.01)
    if(la.norm(predx - approx) <= precision):
        break

plt.show()
```

I have no idea how to fix it, in the end it should be like this: [Kaczmarz animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41221061/kaczmarz-animation)

How I can fix this loop? What I do wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.  You should always include the complete Traceback - formatted as code - if there is an error.

Comment: One of the arrays has three dimensions `(2,1,1)`. You could reduce it to two dimensions by [reshaping](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) it to `(2,1)`.

Comment: nope, i am tracking this and can't find where it 3 dimensional appears